# DenseNet without convolution?

Tags: deep-learning, resnet

The recent paper Densely Connected Convolutional Networks https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06993  has shown that their DenseNet deep learning architecture outperforms state-of-the-art ResNet architectures.   Are there similar papers / repositories for similar architectures but without convolution (RNN/just dense)?

Answer (score 0):

No.

The simple answer is that the convolution itself allows for regularization by exploiting the data locality which is true in most images. This is also the key to achieving a deeper network which is crucial for deeper representations.

Another critical reason is that a dense layer just the size of the input (usually 224*224) will hog down most of your GPU memory so there is little chance today to achieve a dense network for images of this size that or more than a few layers deep. Maybe if you had 10x the GPU RAM you can try to pull that one off... Convolution is simply more economical.